# Show $\exists u,v \in X$ such that $\|u+v\|^2 \neq \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $(X, \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle )$ be an inner product space.  Show that if $X \neq {0}$ then there exist $u,v∈X$ such that $\|u+v\|^2 \neq \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2$.

---

Can we just say that choose $u$ and $v$ such that they are not orthogonal to each other? Then it would work I think but I can't think of specific examples because it is an arbitrary norm.

Comment: How about $u=-v$?

Comment: It's good to put formulas in the title that specifically identify the question, but a title that is _completely_ written in MathJax effectively disables the normal "right-click" functionality of some browsers. So it's also desirable to have some plain-text words in the title as well, even if it's just "Show that".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\neq 0$, it contains a nonzero vector $v$. It also contains $-v$. What is $\Vert v+(-v)\Vert^2$? What is $\Vert v\Vert^2+\Vert-v\Vert^2?$

Comment: $2 \|v\|^2?$?????

Comment: Yes, which is not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for all $\;u,v\in X\;$ we have

$$\left\|u\right\|^2+\left\|v\right\|^2=\left\|u+v\right\|^2:=\left\|u\right\|^2+\left\|v\right\|^2+2\,\text{Re}\,\langle u,v\rangle\iff\text{Re}\,\langle u,v\rangle=0\;\;\;\forall\,u,v\in X$$

But this is absurd since there exists $\;0\neq x\in X\implies \langle x,x\rangle=\text{Re}\,\langle x,x\rangle=\left\|x\right\|^2\neq0\;$